# mysql price handling with valid time interval, limiting join

Tags: mysql

I'm storing my product prices in my whebshop this way:

```
product_id
price
_from: the date which the price is valid from
comment: a FK to a translation, its nullable
```

so I get the current price like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_prices WHERE product_id = 1 AND _from < NOW() LIMIT 1
```

**Now I want to list products thats current price have a comment.**
So far I made this query:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    pp.price
FROM
    product_products p
JOIN product_prices pp
    ON p.id = pp.product_id AND pp._from < NOW()
GROUP BY
    p.id
HAVING
    COUNT(pp.comment) > 0
```

This gave me all the products that ever had a price with comment. Ideally I would add a limit to the join, unfortunately this is not possible :( I'm sure I need a subquery, but so far I can't figure it out.

Any help is appriciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think i got the sollution. Here it is:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    pp.id,
    pp.price,
    pp.comment
FROM
    product_products p
JOIN
    product_prices pp
ON
    pp.id = (SELECT id FROM product_prices WHERE _from < NOW() AND product_id = p.id ORDER BY _from DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE pp.comment IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

one: your first query depends on the order in the table, it would be wise to make sure it does not depend on that, but rather the last price.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM product_prices WHERE product_id = 1 AND pp._from < NOW() order by pp._from desc LIMIT 1
> ```

two: filter by last entry per product

> ```
>  SELECT
>         p.id,
>         pp.price
>     FROM
>         product_products p
>     JOIN product_prices pp
>         ON p.id = pp.product_id AND pp._from < NOW()
>
>     inner join
>     (SELECT pp.product_id, max(pp._from) as last_update FROM product_prices WHERE pp._from < NOW() ) as last
>     on last.product_id=pp.product_id and last.last_update=pp._from
>
>
>     GROUP BY
>         p.id
>     HAVING
>         COUNT(pp.comment) > 0
> ```

Comment: I tried your query. I assume that you left out the "product_prices pp" behind the first join statement. I got this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'pp.product_id' in 'field list'.
Beside that thank you for your effort.

Comment: yeah accidentally copy pasted wrong, edited, should work well now